# Saving all records to next database if the first database is reached its size limit

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am planning to apply web hosting in [godaddy.com](http://godaddy.com) they offer 10 databases and 1GB each. I am creating a site that saving a lots of records. My question is:

1) How can I check the database if it is near 1GB ?

2) How can I automatically select the next database if the previous database reached its limit(1GB) ?

3) How can I echo all results(in those 10 databases), that is related to the set `date`?

4) How can I echo all results(10 databases) depends on the type of the record ? (like: female or male)

If you have suggested a tutorials or anything that is related to my concern. I will appreciate it alot.

Comment: Just find a host that allows a database to be the size you think you need it to be. If you attempt this coding (which is probably possible) after having to ask this question in the first place, you will just end up in a huge mess

Comment: Oh and you should really ask one question per question

Comment: it is one of best site that i looked for(atleasst to my country), and it offers me 100disk space for photo, but what is the reason I would enp up in a huge mess ? can you explain it to me so I can understand it more. thanks

Comment: Anyway, what would happen when your site gets really popular or you just keep adding to it and all of a sudden you need 11gig of database. Then you are really in a mess.

Comment: Show us what you have done for this.

Comment: If you already know you need more that 1Gig and maybe as much as 10Gig or maybe more, then you have done the planning at the right time. Now you have to find and probably pay for the resources to support your known requirements. You are very unlikely to find this on a shared hosting plan

Comment: thansk for the advices

Comment: by the way, can you give me some advices to what web hosting should I go ? I am from philippines.

Comment: First off using another database is going to mess up relationships / constraints and other information unless you plan on handling that in the business aspect side of code which I don't recommend. Let the database do it's job of maintaining good data. Also with the logic on the database it is easier to incorporate API's and other access down the line if you need to. Just find a hosting provider that scales. I am sitting on a College ERP and after 10 years it is only 8.3GB of information. Not sure the issue with 10GB here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name",
    sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB",
    sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

2) You can't do this automaticly

3) You should write own solution for that. Normaly is something as database shard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture). But is used to scalability large databases configured to work with many nodes.

4) like point 3

But is wrong way at all. They give 10 small databases to separate project not for scaling large one. Writing solution like that by yourself will be more expensive than cost large database and maybe never work fine.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Comment: by the way, can you give me some advices to what web hosting should I go ? I am from philippines.